# Yii2 app\controllers\response not found using yii2-widget-depdrop extension

Tags: php, json, yii2

I am new to yii2 and php web app development. I am using dep-drop  for selecting input
depending on parent selection. Now I get an error message in yii2 debugger,

```
exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'app\controllers\Response' not found' in G:\xampp\htdocs\project\controllers\SalesOrderController.php:129 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() #1 {main}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just adding an update because at least in one hand the answer from above can be misleading.

I think that beside issue you mentioned above you had additional issue which is resolved by adding "use yii\helpers\Json;" or something similar because Response is not within namespace you mentioned.

If you want to have a Json Output from your controller and if you want to use Response class for managing action output you will need to use

```
use yii\web\Response;
```

Additionally, example of usage:

```
public function actionApi() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return array(
        "test" => "test",
        "test2" => "test2"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry It was my mistake. 
I just included this :

```
use yii\helpers\Json;
```

Problem Solved. And dep dropdown is now working as expected

Answer (score 0):

please use this code.

```
use yii\web\Response;
```